Vitest: Getting vi.mocked(...).mockImplementation is not a function after hot reloading
I using Vitest with React to make tests. I want to make a "simple" test, to simulate a basic user for my app. The test, when I run npm run test works, the problem is that if I make a change in a file for example that triggers a reload, all the test fails because throws a

TypeError: vi.mocked(...).mockImplementation, vi.mocked(...).mockImplementationOnce, or any method of vi.mocked is not a function.

setupFile.ts:
globalThis.global = globalThis;

import { vi, afterEach } from 'vitest';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import { cleanup } from '@testing-library/react';
import { mockRouter } from './mocks/router';
import { Amplify } from 'aws-amplify';

beforeEach(() => {
  console.log('Before Each')
  //mockAmplify();
  vi.mock('aws-amplify', () => ({
    Auth: {
      currentAuthenticatedUser: vi.fn(),
      currentCredentials: {
        identityId: '',
      },
      signIn: vi.fn(),
      forgotPassword: vi.fn(),
    },
    Storage: {
      put: vi.fn(),
      get: vi.fn(),
      configure: vi.fn(),
    },
    Amplify: {
      configure: vi.fn(),
    },
  }));
  vi.mocked(Amplify.configure).mockImplementation(() => 'Ok');
  mockRouter();
});

afterEach(() => {
  cleanup();
  vi.clearAllMocks();
});

My test file:
import { it, vi } from 'vitest';

import { render, screen, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react';
import { Auth, Amplify } from 'aws-amplify';
import { setupWorker } from 'msw/browser';
import App from '../../app';

import { handlers } from '../mocks/servicesMocks';

import { login } from './flows/login';


const worker = setupWorker();
await worker.start({
  onUnhandledRequest: () => {},
});
worker.use(...handlers);

it('Incorrect Login', async () => {
  // This lines works when I run npm run test, but if I modify my file, it throws error
  // vi.mocked(...).mockRejectValueOnce is not a function
  vi.mocked(Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser).mockRejectedValueOnce(new Error('No user authenticated'));
  render(<App />);
  await login();
});

I have searched online for similar problems, but I haven't had good results. In general, solutions refer to correct use of beforeEach and afterEach/All. I have tried these solutions, but they do not work for me.
I have also tried to delete clearAllMocks, but it hasn't helped.
Also, define the mock in the same test, something like:
it('Incorrect Login', async () => {
  vi.mock('aws-amplify', () => ({Auth: ....});
  vi.mocked(Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser).mockRejectedValueOnce(new Error('No user authenticated'));
  render(<App />);
  await login();
});

But this does not help either.
There are people with similar problems: like this post, but it doesn't help me.
If anyone has any idea for a solution, I would be grateful to know.
